# How to mock android room withTransaction method with Mockk

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, mockk

I'm trying to make some unit tests for my business logic.
I have repository in which I save to room database (2.1.0-rc01) some data from response.
Data saving into different tables with different dao in single transaction.
Code is simplified:

**ItemRepository**

```
suspend fun saveItems(response: Response) {
    val items = response.items.map { it.toLocalItem() }
    val subItems = response.items.flatMap { item ->
            item.subItems.map { it.toLocal(item.id) }
        }

    db.withTransaction {
        db.itemDao().deleteAll()
        db.itemDao().insertAll(items)
        db.subItemDao().insertAll(subItems)
    }
}
```

For unit test I'm using Mockk library. How can I mock room withTransaction method?. withTransaction is declared as

```
suspend fun <R> RoomDatabase.withTransaction(block: suspend () -> R): R
```

I'm trying to writing test

```
@MockK
private lateinit var database: AppDatabase
@MockK
private lateinit var itemDao: ItemDao
@MockK
private lateinit var subItemDao: SubItemDao


@Test
fun checkSaveItems() = runBlocking {
    repository = ItemRepository(database)
    coEvery { database.itemDao() } returns itemDao
    coEvery { database.subItemDao() } returns subItemDao

    //TODO: execute database.withTransaction(block: suspend () -> R)

    coEvery { itemDao.deleteAll() } just Runs
    coEvery { itemDao.insertAll(any()) } just Runs
    coEvery { subItemDao.insertAll(any()) } just Runs

    repository.saveItems(testResponse)

    coVerifySequence {
        itemDao.deleteAll()
        itemDao.insertAll(testItems)
        subItemDao.insertAll(testSubItems)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You first have to enable static mocks for the Android Room KTX method **withTransaction {}**. You also need to capture the suspend lambda function passed to it. This captured function can just be invoked so the code inside it runs. Since you're mocking all the database calls, you don't need a real transaction here.

```
@Before
fun initMocks() {
  MockKAnnotations.init(this)

  mockkStatic(
            "androidx.room.RoomDatabaseKt"
  )

  val transactionLambda = slot<suspend () -> R>()
    coEvery { db.withTransaction(capture(transactionLambda)) } coAnswers {
      transactionLambda.captured.invoke()
    }
}
```

You should then be able to run your code as written.

Comment: Thank you, I'm tryed capturing but test hunged without static mocks

Comment: Had to change -> R to -> Unit to get it working for me

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Andrew's answer, the [mockk documentation for extension functions](https://mockk.io/#extension-functions) shows that if you are mocking an object wide or class wide extension function, you can just use regular `mockk` to achieve that. However, if you are using a *module wide* extension function, like `withTransaction`, you also need to perform `mockkStatic` on the module's class name.